# Why is the ATR Indicator of TA-Lib not working?

Tags: python, ta-lib, binance-api-client

I'm having some problems using the ATR-Indicator in the TA-Lib library. Every other indicator seems to work just fine.

Here's the code in python:

```
import json
import numpy
import talib
import websocket


# *******PARAMETERS
# Name of Socket for BTC in USDT 1min Candle
SOCKET = "wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@kline_1m"
# Arrays
closes = []
highs = []
lows = []

# ***Websocket definition***
def on_open_ws(ws):
    print('opened connection')


def on_close_ws(ws):
    print('closed connection')


def on_message_ws(ws, message):
    json_message = json.loads(message)

    # only watching the candle infos in received message
    candle = json_message['k']

    # getting close, high and low values
    is_candle_closed = candle['x']
    close = float(candle['c'])
    high = float(candle['h'])
    low = float(candle['l'])


    if is_candle_closed:  
        closes.append(close)  # add close price to closes-array
        np_closes = numpy.array(closes)  # convert closes-array in numpy
        c_close = np_closes[-1]  # current close
        p_close = np_closes[-2]  # previous close
        print(len(closes))

        highs.append(high)
        np_highs = numpy.array(highs)
        last_high = np_highs[-1]

        lows.append(low)
        np_lows = numpy.array(lows)
        last_low = np_lows[-1]

        # Set ATR
        atr = talib.ATR(np_highs, np_lows, np_closes, timeperiod=14)
        last_atr = atr[-1]
        print('last atr')
        print(last_atr)

ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(SOCKET, on_open=on_open_ws, on_close=on_close_ws, on_message=on_message_ws)

# Run websocket app
ws.run_forever()
```

The last commands "print('last atr') and print(last_atr) do not print, suggesting that the atr isnt working.

Does somehow have any idea what could be the problem?

I tried using just the last values of high, low and close as well as the non-numpied values, but this doesn't change anything. I'm not even getting the "nan" answer for the first few values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first call of `on_message_ws()` with `is_candle_closed == true` crashes at line `p_close = np_closes[-2]  # previous close` as there is only 1 element in `closes` yet.

After this crash the next call of `on_message_ws()` with `is_candle_closed == true` will continue with `len(closes) == 2` and `len(lows) == len(highs) == 1` and then crash at `talib.ATR()` with `Exception: input array lengths are different`.

And so on.

P.S. I would also suggest to use `numpy.array(closes, dtype='double')` instead of `numpy.array(closes)` as `talib.ATR()` is able to crash with `Exception: input array type is not double`. That's not happening with current data received from binance, but just to be safe I would ensure the arrays are converted to double.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Will be making these changes tmrw =D

Answer (score 0):

So i solved my problem by coding my own ATR, which was a much easier solution then i thought. If it can help anyone heres the code

```
def true_range(high, low, p_close):
    high_low = high - low
    high_close = numpy.abs(high - p_close)
    low_close = numpy.abs(low - p_close)

trange = max(high_low, high_close, low_close)
return trange

# Set TR
    
    last_tr = true_range(last_high, last_low, p_close)
    tr.append(last_tr)
    if len(tr) > ATR_PERIOD:
        del tr[0]

    # Set ATR (SMA smoothing but need RMA)
    atr = sum(tr) / ATR_PERIOD
    print('atr ', atr)
```

ATR_PERIOD is the period you want to set.
For the length of ATR_PERIOD you will obviously get wrong numbers, but afterwards you should be fine